# Is it possible to destroy a phone internally using an app?

Tags: java, android

For my Capstone Project I was thinking about creating a mobile tracker app (kind of like 'Find my Device') that can also destroy the phone's internal system rendering it useless as long as the app is installed in two separate devices where Mobile A can destroy Mobile B if Mobile B is stolen for some reason and is irretrievable.

Edit: sorry if I wasn't clear. The app does not destroy the hardware (e.g.blowing it up) it's just going to destroy it internally so it is unusable

Comment: Stock Android OS would never allow an app to do that

Comment: Oh man...this is actually the title that was accepted. Do you have any suggestions on how I could work around this?

Comment: If it's rooted it may be possible to just wipe the System data. There's likely part of the API that exposes a "wipe phone" method.

Comment: Add a small explosive device under the battery?

Comment: I don't think anything since the Commodore Pet allows a random program to write to a memory address and destroy hardware.

Comment: @KevinO sorry if I was unclear but the app will destroy the software not the hardware

Comment: You can't destroy software because the executable code of a software is stored in the code segment of main memory, and the code segment is not writable

Comment: @Dummy would that be a feasible reason in order to defend my title? I can just work on every other feature my app is intended to do besides destroying the phone

Comment: No, you can't change the binary executable code of a program, you can inject your own code to do whatever you want if you could assume the correct privilege or trick the OS or user to grant you that privilege, but you can't overwrite the executable code of a program that is stored in the code segment of main memory

Comment: @Dummy Thank you for your help. I will consult my adviser about this and see what we can work with.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's actually very easy to severely mess up a phone (although not permanently) just by doing something like screwing with permissions of System apps. I had to deal with this one time, and after accidentally setting a file permission incorrectly, the only way I could boot the phone was to reflash it using ODIN. Permanently messing it up may be difficult, but rendering it unusable until someone that knows what they're doing can fix it is quite easy, and that requires a wipe of the phone to fix anyways.

Comment: Clearly it is somewhat possible. No affiliation from me, but look at [Avast Anti-Theft](https://www.avast.com/anti-theft-features). It hooks into several features, and can do some of what you are investigating.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm guessing not a lot of phone snatchers are going to know what they're doing anyway? Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I think it's built into the OS as a system app, but an external developer wouldn't be able to simply wipe a phone, no. You can erase a device from https://www.google.com/android/find